# windowbuilder in helios with jdk5 doesn't work

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I have installed Eclipse 3.6 (Helios)
  with

- WB_v1.5.2_UpdateSite_for_Eclipse3.6.zip, Eclipse 3.6 (Helios) with

  - WB_v1.6.0_UpdateSite_for_Eclipse3.6.zip, Eclipse 3.6 (Helios) SR2
  - with WB_v1.5.2_UpdateSite_for_Eclipse3.6.zip and Eclipse 3.6 (Helios)
  - SR2 with WB_v1.6.0_UpdateSite_for_Eclipse3.6.2.zip.

When I create a project with a JFrame using JDK6 is ok, when I use JDK5 the JFrame wizard could not be started. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

The [System Requirements](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.wb.doc.user/html/installation/index.html) for WindowBuilder say that JDK 1.6 or higher is required